# How can i add placemarkers (points) from click-event or database to openlayers3 map using geodjango

Tags: python, geodjango, react

How can i plot place-markers in Geodjango using the methods:

- a user click-event from the user on openlayers map preferably in reactjs
- or alternatively from geodjango database that has PointField() attributes

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Marker(models.Model):
    MarkerID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    mpoint = models.PointField()
    objects = models.GeoManager()
    Latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=6)
    Longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=6)

    def shpPoint(request):
        points = ShapefilePoint.objects.kml()
        return render_to_kml("placemarks.kml", {'places': points})

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.Latitude = self.mpoint.y
        self.Longitude = self.mpoint.x
        super(Marker,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: See also: django-leaflet

Comment: Tutorial: http://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/geodjango-maps-with-leaflet.html